# Does XCode ever truncate device's console logs

Tags: xcode, cocoa, logging

I was wondering that if we log a huge bunch of stuff would xcode ever truncate the console logs from the device. I haven't been able to reproduce it but wanted to confirm if Xcode would ever do that?

Comment: I have logged some pretty large JSON strings (with large image base64 strings) before and I have never seen it get truncated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, XCode never truncate device's console logs.Also you can view its outputs with your device connected to your Mac and using Xcode Organizer tool.

Note:-
The above point is applicable only to the prior version of Xcode 8

Comment: As of Xcode 8 this answer is incorrect. Please see the correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584707/nslog-on-devices-in-ios-10-xcode-8-seems-to-truncate-why

Comment: @Compy, Please read my answer first it is clearly mentioned in the note that it is applicable only to the prior version of Xcode 8.

Comment: Please, note that my comment was added on March the 6th 2017, and you edited your post on March the 7th 2017. Clearly at the time of posting my comment was correct, and was likely the reason you updated your post to include this information.

Comment: Yeah I got the popup yesterday but did not realize it was edited long time ago. Sorry it was my bad. Please ignore my last.