# NSLog issues on iOS 10

Tags: nsstring, ios10, foundation, xcode8, nslog

I am finding that on iOS 10 device, NSLog is being truncated for a large string which is not the case on iOS 8 or 9. The only workaround is to print it char by char :

```
        NSString *largeString = .../* a 30000 char string */
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < largeString.length; i++) {
            printf("%c", [largeString characterAtIndex:i]);
        }
```

Why is this and how to fix it ?

Comment: No response, I don't understand whether it's a bug in iOS 10 where NSLog is truncated and desperately need a workaround for printing big NSDictionary having strings as key/value pairs.

Comment: try `printf` instead of `NSLog` like: `printf("%s", [string UTF8String]);`

Comment: How can I print NSDictionary using printf ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39606332/1702413