# How to view full macos os_log_info messages without truncated lines

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, debugging, macos-sierra

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging?language=objc) states

> "Important Log message lines greater than the system’s maximum message
>   length are truncated when stored by the logging system. Complete
>   messages are visible when using the log command-line tool to view a
>   live stream of activity. Bear in mind, however, that streaming log
>   data is an expensive activity."

but when using

```
log stream
```

in terminal i get only partial logs... how to get the full logs, without lines truncated?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to include `--level` and possibly `--type` and/or `--source`:

```
log stream --level debug --type log --source
```

The last two arguments are optional, although it might help you narrow things down if debugging.

> **--level**  ***default*** | ***info*** | ***debug***
>   Shows messages at specified level and below.  The level is a hierarchy. Specifying debug implies debug, info and default.
>
> **--type  activity** | ***log*** | ***trace*** Dictates the type of events to stream from a process.  By default all types are streamed unless otherwise
>   specified. Pass an appropriate --type for each requested type of
>   event.
>
> **--source** Include symbol names and source line numbers for messages, if available.

In terminal you can get more information by using `man log`

Comment: but the log stream doesn't display the full output, but truncated messages

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm not able to reproduce the issue; I get no truncated output.

Comment: When the output is larger than 1024 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584707/nslog-on-devices-in-ios-10-xcode-8-seems-to-truncate-why

Comment: Nah, it can't be that (as it's specific to iOS); I've had no issues getting full output far above 1024 bytes, so it must be something else causing the issue for you.

Comment: i did encounter the same behaviour for macos too (note that you must compile the project under the 10.12 SDK)