# Objective-C, NSTask Buffer Limitation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, nstask

I'm using `NSTask` to run an external utility which returns a long string of data. The problem is that when the returned string exceeds a large amount of data (around 32759 chars) it becomes `null` or truncates the returned string. How do I return the full output?

```
NSTask *myTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[myTask setLaunchPath:myExternalCommand];
[myTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: arg1, arg2, nil]];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[myTask setStandardOutput:pipe];

NSFileHandle *taskHandle;
taskHandle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[myTask launch];
[myTask waitUntilExit];

NSData *taskData;
taskData = [taskHandle readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:taskData
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Output: \n%@", outputString);
// (null or truncated) when stdout exceeds x amount of stdout
```

To test the functionality use `cat` or similar on a large file for the `myExternalCommand`. The issue seems to happen right after the character length of 32759...

solution? I'm not sure, but what might need to happen is to somehow read the return `stdout` in chunks, then append the `outputString`  data if possible.

update: I tried moving `waitUntilExit` after `readDataToEndOfFile` per suggestion, but it did not affect the outcome.

> *please note, I'm looking for an `Obj-C` solution, thanks.

Comment: Read the data before waiting for the task to exit.

Comment: @KenThomases: Hi Ken, so you are meaning put `[myTask waitUntilExit];` at the end of the current function instead? thanks!

Comment: Well, it just should be after the call to `-readDataToEndOfFile`. If it works, I'll write up a full answer with an explanation of what's going on.

Comment: Hi Ken, unfortunately it didn't change the outcome. I think what needs to happen is to somehow allow NSTask to read chunks of the `stdout` and append the data, although I'm not sure how or if that is possible.

Comment: Have you tried logging `taskData` instead of the string you try to create from it? I'm guessing you've got it all but it's not valid UTF-8 data so the attempt to create a string from it fails.

Comment: @KenThomases: I just logged `taskData` and it only returns 29120 characters (as hex bytes), if I covert those bytes to `Ascii` it is equal to 14560 characters. I'm testing it without any special characters just `A-Z`, so should be okay in regard to `UTF-8`, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found on [CocoaDev](https://cocoadev.github.io/NSPipe/):

> “The data that passes through the pipe is buffered; the size of the buffer is determined by the underlying operating system.”
>
> from: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/index.html
>
> The NSPipe buffer limit seems to be 4096 bytes (cf. /usr/include/limits.h: “… #define _POSIX_ARG_MAX 4096 …”)

You can read the output from your `NSTask` asynchronously, using [readabilityHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilehandle/1412413-readabilityhandler?language=objc). Within the handler, use `availableData` to read the output piece-by-piece.

Use a [terminationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask/1408746-terminationhandler?language=objc) to get notified once the task exits, and then set your `readabilityHandler` to nil to stop it from reading.

It's all async, so you'll need to block and wait until the task exits.

Here is a complete sample that works well enough for me. I used a `printf` instead of `NSLog` as it seems that `NSLog` is truncating the output on the console (not sure if that's a [bug or a feature](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63537)). Error checking is omitted and adds some complexity, you will probably want to read `standardError` as well in the same way.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t waitHandle;
NSTask *myTask;
NSMutableData* taskOutput;
        
waitHandle = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        
myTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[myTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/cat"];
[myTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"/path/to/a/big/file", nil]];
[myTask setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
        
taskOutput = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        
[[myTask.standardOutput fileHandleForReading] setReadabilityHandler:^(NSFileHandle *file) {
    NSData *data = [file availableData];
    [taskOutput appendData:data];
}];
        
[myTask setTerminationHandler:^(NSTask *task) {
    [task.standardOutput fileHandleForReading].readabilityHandler = nil;
            
    NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:taskOutput encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    printf("Output: \n%s\n", [outputString UTF8String]);
            
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(waitHandle);
}];
        
[myTask launch];
        
dispatch_semaphore_wait(waitHandle, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283623/233944. Since macOS 10.12 / iOS 10, `NSLog` delegates to the new unified logging, which restricts messages to 1024 characters. For anything longer than that, Apple thinks you should use your own logging system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It appears that my original method works also if I use `printf`, so it seems the `NSLog` limitation is one of the main issues. I was also getting `(null)` when binary data was > `4096` so I'll need to test out your code to see if that resolves things completely. Do you have any idea why NSLog has the limitation like it has? - it seems odd that a logging function wouldn't log (everything).

Comment: sorry, I deleted my last comment by accident, but copied/pasted it again. Would you know if it's possible to stream stdout into the `NSTask` pipe almost continously? Just curious, because that might be useful too.

Comment: The readabilityHandler will be called whenever there's something to read; it's as close to a continuous stream as you could ask for I think.

Comment: It appears your example is much more efficient from the quick testing I did. It seems to use less cpu and memory consumption, thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a task that was throwing a large error immediately, and causing a hang, adding a reader to the stderr solved the issue

```
[[myTask.standardError fileHandleForReading] setReadabilityHandler:^(NSFileHandle *file) {
    NSData *data = [file availableData];
    [taskError appendData:data];
}];
```