# Change system’s maximum message length on macOS

Tags: macos, logging

On macOS, I can see the system logs either via the console, or via the command line `log show`.
When using the later, lines are truncated. The documentation is clear that:

> Log message lines greater than the system’s maximum message length are
>   truncated when stored by the logging system

But I could not find anywhere how to increase this "maximum message length" setting. How can I do so?

Comment: This refers... https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283623/2836621